# System of equations with sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

So im currently trying to find the extremas of the function $f(x,y) = \cos(x+y) + \sin(x) + \sin(y)$

I've already computed the partial derivatives:

$$
f_x(x,y) = \cos(x) - \sin(x+y)\\
f_y(x,y) = \cos(y) - \sin(x+y)
$$
But now i am stuck at solving for the stationary points:
$$
0 = \cos(x) - \sin(x+y)\\
0 = \cos(y) - \sin(x+y)
$$
It would be very nice if someone could help me with this

Comment: Perhaps consider using the identity $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$ before computing the partial derivatives, which will (hopefully) make those equations easier to solve. Similarly, you could consider trying $\sin(x+y)=\cos(x)\sin(x)+\cos(y)\sin(y)$.

Comment: I don't see how this would simplify the situation

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\cos a=\sin b\iff\cos a=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-b\right)$$
$$\iff a\equiv\pm\left(\frac\pi2-b\right)\bmod{2\pi}.$$

Comment: Ok this seems very helpful but how can something be congruent to something negative?

Comment: The signs are irrelevant in a congruence. By definition, $$a\equiv b\bmod c\iff\exists k\in\Bbb Z,\quad a=b+kc.$$

Comment: Would it maybe be easier to use $sin(x + \pi/2) = cos(x)$ ?

Comment: Thank you i was now able to solve it using this identity.

Comment: Yeah yours makes more sense because the $x$ don't cancel out. Im currently struggling computing where those 2 grids that are described by these equations intersect